# What address database does Google Maps use for United Kingdom?

Tags: google-maps, united-kingdom

When searching for a United Kingdom address in Google Maps, is the OS AddressBase or another address database being queried?

Comment: OS has opendata https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-map-local.html if you need more detailed data you will require a licence at cost buildings/addresses.